# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): iOS settings must be set when targeting iOS platform

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-local-notification

Every time I try running my application on and iOS simulator in Visual Studio Code, I keep getting the below error which seems like it has something to do with the Flutter Local Notifications package. I believe I have configured the package as instructed in the documentation. Can anyone please help?

This is the error I keep getting

```
no valid “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:52781/pnunM0l8hsI=/ws
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): iOS settings must be set when targeting iOS platform.
#0      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize
flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:151
#1      main
main.dart:236
#2      _runMain.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:23)
#3      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

The configuration on AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
// import flutter_background_service_ios
import flutter_downloader
import GoogleMaps
import flutter_local_notifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      //GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyC60tYZkISbxvLKJlB0PQVOsdVFeNfNcfo")

//       SwiftFlutterBackgroundServicePlugin.taskIdentifier = "your.custom.task.identifier"

    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { (registry) in
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)}

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    

        // FlutterDownloaderPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback(registerPlugins)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the app is missing the `"aps-environment"` entitlement string, which is required for push notifications to work on iOS. Do you have that there?
This error can also happen due to mismatched configurations between the provisioning profile and the project settings. Can you ensure that the provisioning profile and the project settings are in sync, including the bundle identifier and the certificate used to sign the app.
If the error doesn't go away after trying these, you can delete the app from the simulator and rebuild it with a valid provisioning profile. This will ensure that the app is properly signed with the required entitlements.